# Showing the same fragment on restoring the app from background

Tags: android, android-fragments

Say for instance I have `Activity A`, which has a FrameLayout that can hold one fragment at a time. Lets say that when the Activity is first started it loads `Fragment A` into the FrameLayout, which consists of a ListView. When an item is selected in `Fragment A` it starts up `Fragment B`.Clicking a item on `Fragment B` takes you to the `Fragment C`. The way I am currently doing this is by simply hiding `Fragment A` and then adding `Fragment B` since this preserves `Fragment A's` state. I am of course also adding this fragment transaction to the backstack.

So now `Fragment A` exists on the backstack. Say now I go back to my Android home screen and go to another app. While I am doing this, the Android system decides to destroy my application because the system needs more memory. When I navigate back to my application, how am I supposed to properly restore the same fragment where user left the app.So if user was on `Fragment C` when he minimised the app,and when he reopens it from minimised app `Fragment A` loads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to override `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` methods in your activity (see [**here**](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) ).

```
static final String LAST_FRAGMENT = "userFragment";
...

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putInt(LAST_FRAGMENT, mCurrentFragment);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Then, when creating,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentFragment = savedInstanceState.getInt(LAST_FRAGMENT);
        }
       else { mCurrentFragment = mDefaultFragment }
       ...

       //then you need to load mCurrentFragment
```

Here `mCurrentFragment` is an instance of (the name of, or whatever) last fragment used. You can keep this value updated by overriding the `onPause()` method of the fragment, for example. So each fragment's `onPause()` has to set `mCurrentFragment` to a new value identifying the fragment itself.

**Another way** to do it might be using `SharedPreference`. In each fragment's onPause(), set:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
sp.edit().putInt(LAST_FRAGMENT, $int_identifying_your_fragment ).apply();
```

Then in your activity onCreate,

```
static final String LAST_FRAGMENT = "userFragment";
static int mCurrentFragment;
static int mDefaultFragment = 0;
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mCurrentFragment = sp.getInt(LAST_FRAGMENT, mDefaultFragment);
    ...
    /* then you load desired fragment according to mCurrentFragment
    if (mCurrentFragment == 1), load fragment1 and so on */
```

I've used `int`s here, but you can take any reference of your fragments.

Comment: Surely will try it and get back to you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which method of the two did you use? savedInstanceState or SharedPreference?

Comment: The former one...because I need to store some parameters for the correspoding fragment which I am storing.Also now we have `PersistentBundle`. Any leads on how I can use it effectively for the app.

Comment: Hey...Just one quick suggestion....How about saving the data in `onSaveInstance` of fragment itself instead of passing the variables to main activity and saving the values there.